# Touchpad gesture on wayland gnome 3.18

Tags: gnome, touchpad, wayland, mouse-gestures

I am Using gnome 3.18.2 on wayland. I know there is support for touchpad gesture in wayland but how do I configure it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. No hardware details. No Wayland version. No OS details.

Answer (score 2):

Use Gnome 3.20, which fully supports the touchpad gestures, according to the [release notes](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.20/).